# AngularJS directive variable interpreted as text before interpolated as variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a fairly simple `ng-repeat` that iterates an AngularJS directive to display images from an array of objects, where each JSON object has a `img` attribute with a URL of the image. Everything works fine except in the network tools I can see that the browser is trying to load an image source URL as `{{ data.img }}` before being interpolated into it's actual value, it's driving me crazy trying to figure out why this is happening.

Here are the relevant pieces of my code:

index.html

```
<div ng-repeat="data in obj">
    <feed-item></feed-item>
</div>
```

feedItem.html (directive)

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="{{ data.img }}" />
</div>
```

Angular directive

```
app.directive("feedItem", function() {
   return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'assets/directives/feedItem.html',
        replace: true
   };
});
```

This results in the images rendering fine, but as mentioned the following shows up in the network tools:

[image]

All of the 2 images from the array of JSON objects are loaded fine as you can see, but I have the extra request the browser is trying to make, and the "initiator" column just says "other" which is not very helpful. Any idea why this request is being sent?

Comment: have you tried using ng-src?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As matthewdaniel said, ng-src might solve your problem. It stops the browser from trying to load that source of the image before angular can get going, you use it just like the 'src' attribute on a normal image.